# Save and get ArrayList<Integer> Android

Tags: android, json, save, sharedpreferences

How can I save an ArrayList and How can I get it back?
I tryed using SharedPreferences but probably i did some mistakes!

Can You help me maybe with some exemples?

Thanx!
:)

Comment: You should use Sqllite DB, check the following link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

Declare these 2 variables:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor prefseditor;
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
prefseditor = prefs.edit();
```

You have to pass the a string key and a arraylist,

```
public boolean setStringSetpref(String key, ArrayList array) {
        status = true;
        try {
            this.array = array;
            s = new HashSet<String>(array);
            prefseditor.putStringSet(key, s);
            prefseditor.apply();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = false;
        }
        return status;
    }
```

To get the values,

```
public ArrayList<String> getStringSetPref(String key) {
        s = prefs.getStringSet(key, null);
        array = new ArrayList<String>(s);
        return array;
    }
```

Comment: Thanx your answare is very nice but i need to save an ArrayList<Integer> ... do you have any idea about how can i do that? Thanx 4 ur time! :)

Comment: Convert integer to string and save them, when retrieving convert from string to integer.... don't see any other way to save integer array in sharedpreferences..

Comment: Thanx but i solved using Gson and sharedpreferences!

Comment: Welcome. Nice to know you found solution